# filtering rows by its second values in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I am new in Matlab I hope this question worth it.
I have 2 sets of numbers.
a=[0;0.01;0.02;0.03;...]  (4187*1)
b=[0;0.3;0.4;0.1;0.23;...]  (4187*1)
By defining f=[a b] (4187*2) Matrix I want to filter my rows by condition on b value (b>0.05) and I want to see the results in (a b) format.
Can you help me on writing this program?

Comment: What do you want to do with the rows? Delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter your rows depending on values in `b` then you can do this:

```
f = [a,b];
f = f((f(:,2)<=0.05),:);
```

This will keep all of the values less than or equal to `0.05` based on the values from `b`. This is assuming you want to delete all the rows of `b>0.05`

If you want to keep the values of `b>0.05` then you would use this:

```
f = [a,b];
f = f((f(:,2)>0.05),:);
```

Comment: this is working but omits all b values and displays just a values.
It is work for me but it would be nice if it shows b values in front of a values like:
0 2;
0.002 5

Comment: You want the format also in [a,b]? Can you show me a sample of what you are getting it should not be omitting the b values. I added a colon after my first post. This colon ensures that it will return both columns. (f(:,2)<=0.05),:) make sure you have the colon after the comma.